# REVERSE_PORTRAIT is not detectable?

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, screen-orientation

I am developing an App, and I want whenever the user change the orientation of the device I display the current orientation of the device. Actually, I achieved this step, but when i rotate the device to be in `REVERSE_PORTRAIT` the screen does not obey the rotation, in other words, my screen can not be in the `REVERSE_PORTRAIT`.

In the manifest file, I changed the value of `android:ScreenOrientation` to be `user`, but still in the same problem, all the three orientations `PORTRAIT`, `LANDSCAPE` and `REVERSE_LANDSCAPE` are detectable EXCEPT `REVERSE_PORTRAIT`

How can I find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use fullSensor if you want every possible orientation

"fullSensor"    The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor for any of the 4 orientations. This is similar to "sensor" except this allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations, regardless of what the device will normally do (for example, some devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those). Added in API level 9.

all the possible values for screenOrientation and some explanations are here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html